# match string to list of regex patterns if statement

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and trying to match a string to a list of regexes.

```
import re
str = 'foo'
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listofRegex = [r'some*regex[.]pattern', r'some*regex[.]pattern2']

if str in list1 or re.match(rex in listofRegex, str):
    ...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just combine the expressions into one?

Comment: You can iterate over the `listOfRegex` and try to match each regex one by one. For a beginner, a `for`-loop is suitable for that.

Comment: Okay, I am new to Python, how can I achieve this? @ninesalt

Comment: If you are not familiar enough with Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: Take a look at the `any()` function. `any(re.match(rex, str) for rex in listofRegex)`

Comment: so I can do something like `if str in list1 or any(re.match(rex, str) for rex in listofRegex)` ? @Barmar

Comment: yes, why couldn't you?

Comment: If you can write it by itself you can also combine it with another test using `or`. That's just a general principle.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate your expressions with the or operator `|`. You can then test your sentence/word on all of them together.

```
import re

r1 = r'lo'
r2 = r'hel.'

listofregex = [r1, r2]
regcombined = re.compile('|'.join(listofregex))
allmatched = regcombined.findall('hello')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this out. Do you know if @Barmar suggestion will work? I am wondering if I can combine his suggestion into my original if block like so 
`if str in list1 or any(re.match(rex, str) for rex in listofRegex)`

Comment: @henrylee His answer should work too but it's a slightly more expensive operation.

Comment: Okay, do you think my if statement will work however if I combine it with his suggestion? 

`if str in list1 or any(re.match(rex, str) for rex in listofRegex)`

Or should his suggestion be in its own if block

Comment: @henrylee `any()` returns a boolean value, so it should work fine.